# Why is the degeneracy factor for Bose Einstein distribution set to 1 automatically?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate, bosons, identical-particles

In https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/schwartz/files/12-bec.pdf, the article says
"With Bose-Einstein statistics, we determined that using the grand canonical ensemble the expected number of particles in a state i is"

$$\langle{n}_{i}\rangle=\frac {1}{e^{\beta(\varepsilon _{i}-\mu )}-1}$$

And it goes on and derive the relationship between the total number of particles and the number of particles in the ground state.

$$N=\sum_{n_x,n_y,n_z=0}\frac{1}{e^{\beta\varepsilon_{1}(n_x^2+n_y^2+n_z^2)}\left(\frac{1}{\langle{n_0}\rangle}+1\right)-1}$$

However, as I understand, the equation for the expected number of particles in a state i is

$$\langle{n}_{i}\rangle=\frac {g_i}{e^{\beta(\varepsilon _{i}-\mu )}-1}$$
where $g_i$ is the degeneracy of energy level $i$. My question is why can I assume $g_i=1$ in this case since wouldn't that affect the answer?

Comment: "My question is why can I assume $g_i=1$ in this case since wouldn't that affect the answer?" You haven't given us enough context to understand why you, in this situation, should or should not use $g_i=1$. If the context is in the linked pdf, it would be nice if you could include that context in the body of your question, since the link is subject to rot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected number of particles in a given state $i$ is given by $$\langle n_i\rangle = \frac{1}{e^{\beta(\epsilon_i-\mu)}-1}$$

If there are $g(\epsilon)$ states which all have energy $\epsilon$, then the expected number of particles with energy $\epsilon$ is given by
$$\langle n(\epsilon)\rangle = \frac{g(\epsilon)}{e^{\beta(\epsilon-\mu)}-1}$$

In other words, in your second expression $i$ does not label a *state* but rather an *energy level*; $g_i$ is then the number of states with that energy.